# Failed to install SingleCellExperiment R package on Linux via RStudio Server

Tags: r, linux, bioinformatics, rstudio-server

I tried to install SingleCellExperiment on a Linux server with

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("SingleCellExperiment")
```

However, I got such error information, It seems the error is about the unmatched slot classes. I'm new to single-cell analyses and don't know how to fix this problem.

```
Error in makePrototypeFromClassDef(properties, ClassDef, immediate, where) : 
  in making the prototype for class “SingleCellExperiment” elements of the prototype failed to match the corresponding slot class: rowRanges (class "GenomicRangesORGRangesList" )
Error: unable to load R code in package ‘SingleCellExperiment’
Execution halted
```

My session information is as follows:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Scientific Linux 7.4 (Nitrogen)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[7] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] SummarizedExperiment_1.6.5 DelayedArray_0.2.7        
 [3] matrixStats_0.57.0         Biobase_2.36.2            
 [5] GenomicRanges_1.38.0       GenomeInfoDb_1.22.1       
 [7] XVector_0.26.0             IRanges_2.20.2            
 [9] S4Vectors_0.24.4           BiocGenerics_0.32.0       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5             BiocInstaller_1.26.1  
 [3] pillar_1.4.4           compiler_3.6.0        
 [5] BiocManager_1.30.10    bitops_1.0-6          
 [7] tools_3.6.0            zlibbioc_1.22.0       
 [9] lattice_0.20-38        lifecycle_0.2.0       
[11] tibble_3.0.1           gtable_0.3.0          
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.3        rlang_0.4.9           
[15] Matrix_1.2-17          cli_2.2.0             
[17] rstudioapi_0.13        ggrepel_0.9.0         
[19] GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.2 dplyr_1.0.0           
[21] generics_0.1.0         vctrs_0.3.1           
[23] grid_3.6.0             tidyselect_1.1.0      
[25] glue_1.4.2             R6_2.5.0              
[27] fansi_0.4.1            ggplot2_3.3.2         
[29] purrr_0.3.4            magrittr_2.0.1        
[31] scales_1.1.1           ellipsis_0.3.1        
[33] assertthat_0.2.1       colorspace_2.0-0      
[35] RCurl_1.95-4.11        munsell_0.5.0         
[37] crayon_1.3.4
```

More information from the console while installation:

```
Bioconductor version 3.10 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Installing package(s) 'SingleCellExperiment'
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.10/bioc/src/contrib/SingleCellExperiment_1.8.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 614930 bytes (600 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 600 KB

* installing *source* package ‘SingleCellExperiment’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning messages:
1: no function found corresponding to methods exports from ‘DelayedArray’ for: ‘acbind’, ‘arbind’ 
2: multiple methods tables found for ‘type’ 
3: multiple methods tables found for ‘rowSums’ 
4: multiple methods tables found for ‘colSums’ 
5: multiple methods tables found for ‘rowMeans’ 
6: multiple methods tables found for ‘colMeans’ 
7: multiple methods tables found for ‘splitAsList’ 
8: replacing previous import ‘BiocGenerics::dims’ by ‘Biobase::dims’ when loading ‘SummarizedExperiment’ 
9: replacing previous import ‘BiocGenerics::type’ by ‘DelayedArray::type’ when loading ‘SummarizedExperiment’ 
10: no function found corresponding to methods exports from ‘SummarizedExperiment’ for: ‘acbind’, ‘arbind’ 
Warning: undefined slot classes in definition of "SingleCellExperiment": rowRanges(class "GenomicRangesORGRangesList")
Error in makePrototypeFromClassDef(properties, ClassDef, immediate, where) : 
  in making the prototype for class “SingleCellExperiment” elements of the prototype failed to match the corresponding slot class: rowRanges (class "GenomicRangesORGRangesList" )
Error: unable to load R code in package ‘SingleCellExperiment’
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘SingleCellExperiment’
* removing ‘/mnt/sas0/AD/jli2274/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/SingleCellExperiment’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp2EIKEa/downloaded_packages’
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: ade4, annotate, AnnotationDbi, ape, assertthat,
  backports, BH, Biobase, BiocGenerics, BiocParallel, bit, bit64, blob, boot, checkmate, class, cli, cluster,
  coda, codetools, colorspace, data.table, DBI, DelayedArray, deldir, DESeq2, digest, doParallel, dplyr, e1071,
  evaluate, expm, fit.models, foreach, formatR, Formula, genefilter, geneplotter, generics, GenomeInfoDb,
  GenomeInfoDbData, GenomicRanges, ggplot2, glue, GO.db, gtable, hierfstat, highr, Hmisc, htmlTable, htmltools,
  htmlwidgets, igraph, impute, IRanges, iterators, jsonlite, KernSmooth, knitr, labeling, lambda.r, lattice,
  latticeExtra, lazyeval, locfit, magrittr, markdown, MASS, Matrix, matrixStats, mgcv, mime, mvtnorm, nlme, nnet,
  pheatmap, pillar, pkgconfig, pls, plyr, preprocessCore, prettyunits, R6, raster, Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, RCurl,
  reshape2, rlang, robust, robustbase, rrBLUP, rrcov, RSQLite, rstudioapi, S4Vectors, scales, segmented, seqinr,
  sf, shiny, sp, spatial, spData, spdep, stringi, stringr, SummarizedExperiment, survival, tibble, units, vctrs,
  vegan, WGCNA, withr, XML, xtable, XVector, yaml, zlibbioc
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘SingleCellExperiment’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: The installation goes through for me (Fedora 31, R 3.6.2). Can you provide the relevant parts of the compiling stack that was produced while installing the package?

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the incomplete information! I updated this question with all console output.

Comment: It says that the installation path for some packages is not writable. Perhaps this is a venue you could explore further.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I succeeded to install it after install all of the packages mentioned in the error information in my user library instead of the system library. Because I don't have the administrative right to update those package in the system library.